# gsub producing a range rather than desired expression in R

Tags: r, format, gsub

I would like to read in a table then use gsub to return a part of the text. I know gsub requires a character vector format. Instead of getting the desired samp list of 'C516_A1_B1' and pat list of'C516' etc, I get'1:5'. What is the simplest way to fix this? Thanks!

```
bamlist <- read.table('pathtotxtfile.txt')

for (y in bamlist) {
    samp <- gsub('EPICC_(C\\S+)_S1\\S+$','\\1', bamlist)
    pat <- gsub('(C\\d+)_\\S+$','\\1', samp)
}
```

bamlist:

```
EPICC_C516_A1_B1_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_A1_G4_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B1_G7_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B1_G8_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B3_B1_S1-GRCh38.bam
```

Comment: You are loop over the `bamlist`, but within the loop, the 'x' is 'bamlist' instead of 'y'

Comment: thank you, it's now working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why loop, `sub` is vectorized over `x`.

```
samp <- sub("^[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*$", "\\1", bamlist)
pat <- sub("(^[^_]+)_.*$", "\\1", samp)

samp
#[1] "C516_A1_B1" "C516_A1_G4" "C516_B1_G7" "C516_B1_G8"
#[5] "C516_B3_B1"
pat
#[1] "C516" "C516" "C516" "C516" "C516"
```

**Data**

```
bamlist <- scan(what = character(), text = "
EPICC_C516_A1_B1_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_A1_G4_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B1_G7_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B1_G8_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B3_B1_S1-GRCh38.bam
")
```

## Edit

Following user @akrun's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882583/gsub-producing-a-range-rather-than-desired-expression-in-r/62882710#comment111200547_62882710), here is a way to apply the above code to a data.frame.

```
lapply(bamlist, function(y){
  samp <- sub("^[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*$", "\\1", y)
  pat <- sub("(^[^_]+)_.*$", "\\1", samp)
  data.frame(samp = samp, pat = pat)
})
#$X
#        samp  pat
#1 C516_A1_B1 C516
#2 C516_A1_G4 C516
#3 C516_B1_G7 C516
#4 C516_B1_G8 C516
#5 C516_B3_B1 C516
```

The data would now be

```
X <- scan(what = character(), text = "
EPICC_C516_A1_B1_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_A1_G4_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B1_G7_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B1_G8_S1-GRCh38.bam
EPICC_C516_B3_B1_S1-GRCh38.bam
")

bamlist <- data.frame(X)
```

Comment: I think there is a difference here because the OP was calling it directly on the data.frame created with `read.table`